# jsdoc fails to run and complains about an unexpected token

Tags: conda, python-sphinx, jsdoc

I have a simple test program

```
(docs) [dsargrad@sdbie-sargrad test]$ cat main.js
/** 
 *  A person generator
 * 
 *  @param {string} name The persons full name
 *  @param {number} age The persons age
 *  @param {boolean} isDeveloper The person is a developer
 */
function createPerson(name, age, isDeveloper) {
    return {
        name: name,
        age: age,
        isDeveloper: isDeveloper
    }
}
```

jsdoc version 3.6.10 complains when I try to generate documentation

```
(docs) [dsargrad@sdbie-sargrad test]$ jsdoc main.js 
/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/opts-arg.js:7
    opts = { mode: 0o777, fs, ...opts }
                              ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at Object.load (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/loader.js:105:18)
    at Requizzle.requizzle (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/requizzle.js:87:31)
    at infectProxy (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/loader.js:79:31)
    at Module.targetModule.require.filepath [as require] (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/loader.js:97:44)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I think this is a simple configuration problem (perhaps with babel or something like that), but I am not sure how to fix this.

It turns out that I even see this when I run jsdoc standalone without any arguments:

```
(docs) [dsargrad@sdbie-sargrad test]$ jsdoc
/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/opts-arg.js:7
    opts = { mode: 0o777, fs, ...opts }
                              ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at Object.load (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/loader.js:105:18)
    at Requizzle.requizzle (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/requizzle.js:87:31)
    at infectProxy (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/loader.js:79:31)
    at Module.targetModule.require.filepath [as require] (/home/dsargrad/.conda/envs/docs/lib/node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/requizzle/lib/loader.js:97:44)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I installed sphinx and sphinx-js as follows:

```
  conda install -c conda-forge sphinx
  conda install -c conda-forge sphinx-js
```

I am using conda version 4.10.3

```
(docs) [dsargrad@sdbie-sargrad test]$ conda --version
conda 4.10.3
```

I activated my conda environment:

```
conda create --name docs python=3.9
conda activate docs
```

I then installed jsdoc this way:

```
npm install -g jsdoc
```

[image]

It would seem that everything is installed properly, and that the versions I am using are also quite recent.

How can I fix this inability to properly run jsdoc?

Comment: Seems like a node version problem

Comment: MrMythical. You were exactly right. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the way that I installed jsdoc was the problem.

The version of node that I found within my conda environment was outdated.

I've gotten past this by eliminating conda in the installation process.

As a follow up. I've now installed like this:

```
conda create -name docs python=3.9
conda activate docs
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 nodejs
conda install  -c conda-forge sphinx
conda install  -c conda-forge sphinx-js
```

This seems to give me a version of sphinx and node that work together with jsdoc.

I also tried to install like this. Oddly it gave me a much older version of sphinx

```
conda create -name docs python=3.9
conda activate docs
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 nodejs
conda install  -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 sphinx
conda install  -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 sphinx-js
```